# Power spectrum from autocorrelation function with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, correlation

I have some dynamic light scattering data. The machine pumps out the autocorrelation function, and a count-rate.

I can do a simple fit to the ACF

```
ACF = exp(-D*q^2*t)
```

and obtain the diffusion coefficient.

I want to obtain the same `D` from the power spectrum. I have been able to create a power spectrum in two ways -- from the Fourier transform of the ACF, and from the count rate. Both agree, but the power spectrum does not look like in the one in the books, so I'm not sure how to use it to work out the line width.

Attached is an image from a PDF that shows what you should get, and what I get from MATLAB. Can anyone make sense of whats going on?

I have used the code of answer #3 on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949324/calculate-autocorrelation-using-fft-in-matlab) question. The resulting autocorrelation comes out exactly the same as

1. the machine gives me and
2. using MATLAB's `autocorr` command on the photoncount data.

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience in this area, but it would surprise me to get a good fit for the ACF, and a terrible fit for the FFT. I have two suggestions. First, post a plot of the autocorrelation data along with your fit to the exponential; is the fit really all the great?. Second, the fourier transform of the decaying exponential can be done analytically: see entry 205 on the wikipedia page for Fourier Transforms. So given your fit, you should able to plot the expected FFT as well. Add this to your FFT plot. This might give some insight into the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I haven't actually tried just doing it to the fit. I'll give that a go and as you said it may give me some insight into my problem. I think another problem is my sampling, I'm not really telling matlab anything about the time delay or what range to plot it over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compute the Fourier transform from short sequences of data it often looks very noisy. There are a number of reasons for this. One reason is that the statistics of individual Fourier components are not Gaussian, and so averaging the spectra across multiple samples of data will only slowly improve the quality of the estimate.

Another causes of "noisiness" in empirical spectra behavior is that you are applying (to a finite data sample) a transform which involves a pathological [sinc function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) and which assumes an infinite length signal. To diminish this problem, it helps to apply a ["windowing-function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) to your data before computing the Fourier transform. One of the more complicated but also more powerful windowing approaches is the use of so-called 'Slepian tapers'.

MATLAB conveniently implements well-known windows in functions such as `hamming` and `hann`.

Comment: Hi cjh. I read up more about windowing-functions and found some information which included the hamming and hann commands. I think my problem lies in the fact that I am not giving matlab enough input - as specified above. I will try a few things, but I am getting close. I found some code that plots an exponential decay over a certain range, and then its shifted-FFT, which looks exactly like it should in the book. So I will try to apply the same kind of operations to my data.

Comment: Hi Steve, glad it helped. Two thoughts: [1] the low-frequency and high-frequency components of the spectra tend to respond differently to the windowing procedure and the addition of more data; low-frequencies, I think, require more data for accurate estimation; also, the windowing functions may also suppress some (very) low frequencies in your spectrum. [2] As Dan Becker noted, there may be implicit analytical expressions for `D` that bypass the calculation of the entire spectrum. But I have the feeling that you have a good reason for taking the route you've chosen. Good luck!