# MATLAB Code Clarification

Tags: matlab

I recently visited this page in order to determine the frequency from signal data in MATLAB:

[Determine frequency from signal data in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261122/determine-frequency-from-signal-data-in-matlab)

And in this page, an answerer responded with the following code:

```
[maxValue,indexMax] = max(abs(fft(signal-mean(signal))));
```

---

From what I can see, a Fast Fourier Transform is taken on a signal named `signal`, its magnitude is kept by using 'abs', and the max value is computed. The max value will be in `maxValue`, and the `indexMax` will contain the position of the `maxValue`. However, can someone explain what is meant by `signal-mean`, and what the purpose of it?

Comment: Try `x = 1:numel(signal); plot(x,signal,x,signal-mean(signal),'r')` to visually see what it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically normalize the vector `signal` so it has mean zero (subtracts the mean from `signal`). So `signal` - `mean(signal)` looks like `signal` except that is shifted on the `y` axis so it has a zero mean. Hope it is clear.

In the example you posted in the link, the mean of the signal is around `-2`, so by subtracting the mean you end up with a the signal shifted up around the `y=0` axis.

Comment: +1 - Correct.  This detrends the mean so that the signal is more or less centred at 0 and would thus make the signal centred at `y=0`.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [vsoftco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25026569/2586922), `signal-mean(signal)` subtracts the mean of the signal.

However, the key point is: *why* is this is done? If you don't subtract the mean, it's very likely that the maximum peak in the FFT appears at frequency 0 (DC component). But you don't want to detect that as the "frequency" of your signal, even if it truly is the highest spectral component. So you *remove that zero-frequency component* by subtracting the mean. That way, the `max` operation will detect the maximum *non-zero* frequency component, which is probably what you want.